# Credit Card Ticket Refund

Tags: tickets, airlines

I issue a Airline(KU) ticket with my credit card, later I cancel my that CC, now I refund the ticket, how will I get the money back?

Comment: Did you close the account as well as cancelling the card? If you have new card but the same account, the refund should be able to be processed by the card company

Answer (score 2):

Most businesses will only refund card payments to the card that was used for the original payment. This is to stop money-laundering.

If you have cancelled the credit card you used for payment the airline obviously can't refund to that card. You will have to talk to the airline to find out what other arrangements they are willing to make.

Note that at present many airlines are not paying refunds because of the cash flow problems occasioned by the COVID-19 pandemic. You might find that the only option they will give you is a voucher for a future flight.

Comment: You can refund to a cancelled card if the account is still open.